# How to have timestamp (hour:minute) as prefix to a recurring task started before but recurring in the current day in an agenda view for the current?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

The current day is 2024-03-30 .

I have the following sample agenda items:

```
* Future
** A meeting non-recurring :meeting:
SCHEDULED: <2024-03-30 Sat 11:00>
** Meeting recurring starting today :meeting:
SCHEDULED: <2024-03-30 Sat 09:00+1d>
** Meeting recurring started before :meeting:
SCHEDULED: <2024-03-27 Sat 18:00+1d>
The resulted agenda view for today is as follows:
```

Here is the agenda view for days before the current day, the current day, and after that:

```
10 days-agenda (W13-W14):
Wednesday  27 March 2024
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
Thursday   28 March 2024
Friday     29 March 2024
Saturday   30 March 2024
  8:00...... ----------------
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 10:00...... ----------------
 11:00...... Scheduled:  A meeting non-recurring                                                                                       :meeting:
 12:00...... ----------------
 13:21...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 14:00...... ----------------
 16:00...... ----------------
 18:00...... ----------------
 20:00...... ----------------
 Sched. 3x:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                                          :meeting:
Sunday     31 March 2024
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
Monday      1 April 2024 W14
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
Tuesday     2 April 2024
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
Wednesday   3 April 2024
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
Thursday    4 April 2024
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
Friday      5 April 2024
  9:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring starting today                                                                              :meeting:
 18:00...... Scheduled:  Meeting recurring started before                                                                              :meeting:
```

Here is my settings related:

```
(setq org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda . " %?-12t% s")
        (todo . "%?-12t")
        (tags . "%?-12t")
        (search . "%?-12t")))
```

Note, with the same configuration, "Meeting recurring started before" does not have the expected timestamp shown for the current day, but have for the days after the current day!

How can I have the consistent presence of timestamp for all scheduled recurring or not, for current and for future, regardless when the recurring start?